# showing subversion history recursively below subfolder/path

Tags: svn, version-control

`svn help log` doesn't give me an option to see the history recursively.

`svn log -l3 --recursive SVN_ROOT_URL` does not work. I would expect that it gives me the last 3 commits below SVN_ROOT_URL.

This is really annoying. I always have to start my IDE or look at team-city to see the last commits on a project (though I am not sure which svn command these tools execute behind the scenes).

I think this feature is very important and hope it is supported out of the svn-CLI box without high bash-scripting effort.

Answer (score 31, accepted):

`svn log` is already doing it recursively. My error was, that I didn't do an `svn update` before.

If you don't want to do a `svn update` to "protect" your working-copy do the log command on the server destination:

```
$ svn info .
...
URL: http://rep.com/svn/foo
...
$ svn log -v http://rep.com/svn/foo
```

i use the verbose `-v` flag to also see the touched files.

Comment: If you use an IDE or another tool for SVN update, note that it may have SVN-updated only the sub-directories, but not the parent directory (depending on how the IDE imported the SVN working copy), causing svn log command not to show all revisions. Doing svn update from the command line in the actual directory surely fixes this issue

Answer (score 2):

- For linux : svn update before svn log
- For windows : <kbd>right click</kbd> on the folder and show log (no need to update firstly)

It's really confusing